# how to save image and remaining fields (string) of that table at same time in spring java

Tags: spring, rest, api

I am trying to develop REST API that used to save data in POSTGRESQL with hibernate.
this REST API basically save the profile of user during registration, that has one image and 4 other String fields like name, gender, job etc.

I successfully saved the image in DB.

Now my problem is to save the image and other fields at the same time, like API hit once that save image and other string fields

code for saving the image is

```
 @RequestMapping(path="/a",  method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)//
   public void Saving(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ) throws Throwable
   {
       EventSpeaker sp=new EventSpeaker();
       sp.setPic(file.getBytes());

       service.savespecker(sp);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to achieve what you are looking for. For example; let's assume your `<form>` looks like as below.

```
<form id="form-id">
 <input type="file" name="file"/>
 <input type="text" id="gender"/>
 <input type="text" id="job"/>
</form>
```

On the controller;

```
@RestController
public class YourController {

   @RequestMapping(path="/a",  method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)//
   public void Saving(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                      @ModelAttribute("gender") String gender,
                      @ModelAttribute("job") String job) throws Throwable {
         //your code
   }
}
```

As you could see, the image file has to be captured as `@RequestParam` and other text inputs as `@ModelAttribute` using their ids. Those model attributes are extracted from spring MVC model. If you are using JQuery you will have to add these form inputs to `FormData`. 
A good reference on how `@ModelAttribute` works can be found here; https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation